# Format document in visual studio doesn't fix indentation in some parts of code

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Edit->Advanced->Format document in visual studio doesn't fix indentation of some of the code in my document. Why?
Some examples:

too many tabs:

[image: too many tabs:]

also improperly intended:

[image: also improperly intended:]